# GJS/GTK Why can't I replace gtk treeview model (columns)?

Tags: gtk, gjs

I am starting off with an empty table (liststore with one column)

[image: beginning state with empty table]

I want users to be able to import a CSV file and have the contents displayed.
Importing the file works and the CSV data is indeed displayed, but the original column (titled "No Data") stays. 
How do I get rid of it?

[image: Table with retained "No Data" column]

I have tried removing the tree view element and even the containers (but when I do that I can't get them to display again...

I saw in the gtk docs that replacing treeView.set_model(listStore) should completely replace the existing model and columns, but it doesn't seem to...

what I'm doing now is this:

```
this._listStore = new Gtk.ListStore();

let coltypes = [GObject.TYPE_STRING];
this._listStore.set_column_types(coltypes);

// Create the treeview
this._treeView = new Gtk.TreeView({
  expand: true
});

this._treeView.set_model(this._listStore);
// Create a cell renderer for when bold text is needed
let bold = new Gtk.CellRendererText({
  weight: Pango.Weight.BOLD
});

// Create a cell renderer for normal text
let normal = new Gtk.CellRendererText();

// Create the columns for the address book
let defCol = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn({
  title: "No Data"
});

// Pack the cell renderers into the columns
defCol.pack_start(bold, true);

// Set each column to pull text from the TreeView's model
defCol.add_attribute(bold, "text", 0);

// Insert the columns into the treeview
this._treeView.insert_column(defCol, 0);
```

Then, when the csv file is uploaded I try to update the table with something like this:

```
this._listStore = new Gtk.ListStore();
// this._treeView.add(this._listStore);

let coltypes = [];
this.data.headers.forEach((h) => {

  coltypes.push(GObject.TYPE_STRING);

});

print(coltypes);
this._listStore.set_column_types(coltypes);

// Replace the treeview

this._treeView.set_model(this._listStore);
/*
this._treeView = new Gtk.TreeView ({
    expand: true,
    model: this._listStore });
   */
// Create cell renderers
let normal = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
let bold = new Gtk.CellRendererText({
  weight: Pango.Weight.BOLD
});

// Create the columns for the address book

for (k = 0; k < this.data.headers.length; k++) {
  print('***key is : ' + k + ', val is : ' + this.data.headers[k] + ' of type : ' + typeof(this.data.headers[k]));

  // let col=k;
  this[`col_${k}`] = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn({
    title: this.data.headers[k]
  });
  this[`col_${k}`].pack_start(normal, true);
  if (k == 0) {
    this[`col_${k}`].add_attribute(normal, "text", k);
  } else {
    this[`col_${k}`].add_attribute(normal, "text", k);
  }
  try {
    this._treeView.insert_column(this[`col_${k}`], k);
  } catch (err) {
    print(err);
  }

}

// Put the data in the table
let i;
for (i = 0; i < this.data.csva.length; i++) {

  let row = this.data.csva[i];
  print('trying to push : ' + row[0].toString());
  print('... the data is of type : ' + typeof(row[1]));
  let iter = this._listStore.append();

  // this._listStore.set (iter, [0, 1, 2],
  // [contact[0].toString(), contact[1].toString(), contact[2].toString()]);

  this._listStore.set(iter, Object.keys(this.data.headers), row);

}
```

Why is that initial column still there? how do I get rid of it?

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [Gtk.TreeView.remove_column()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-remove-column). In Python, this would be:

```
for column in this._treeView.get_columns():
    this._treeView.remove_column(column)
```

You would of course do this for every time you need to remove all the columns in the treeview before adding the columns from the CSV.